Dark Reader for Ubuntu? How do I actively monitor color balance of screen and automatically invert colors when needed to reduce eye strain?
I am confident there is a way to use the computer itself to actively monitor the colors on the screen, measure the ratio (balance) of light to dark pixels and automatically invert window colors as needed to favor a dark balance.  This could be considered a dynamic display dark mode (DDDM).
Does anyone have ideas how this could be done effectively?
There currently exists an extension for Chrome and Firefox browsers called "Dark Reader" which does exactly this, and I am currently using it and loving it.  Boy, it would be nice to apply the same technology to my entire Ubuntu desktop experience.
A full screen inversion is certainly not the answer.  I tried that early on.  Some windows are mostly black and some windows are mostly white, so a universal inversion doesn't really solve anything.
Background: I find that when I'm viewing a screen that is mostly white with black text my eyes feel strained.  The moment that I invert that screen so that it becomes mostly black with white text, I feel immediate relief. I have gotten pretty good at noticing when it's needed and then tapping Meta+U to invert windows as needed to create a more pleasant (and healthier?) experience.

have you looked at Extension Manager - Dark Variant to see if that meets your needs?

The desktop color theme extension Dark Variant seems to be a significant improvement.  Thanks for mentioning it.  While not a panacea, it does meet much of my need.

should I post that as an answer?

@graham   Technically I suppose it doesn't directly answer the question as stated.  However, it did mostly meet my need.  If you did post it as an answer I would select it as an solution.

Thanks. Now posted as requested.

Whilst not directly answering the question (for which there appears no ready solution) there is a GNOME Extension called Dark Variant which could address most of the requirements.
It does require the installation of Extension Manager and if not already installed it can be done so using
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager


